# How to initialize storage using tezos-client

Tags: rpc, tezos-client

I have a contract with storage as

```
let%init storage = (Map : (key_hash, nat)map)
```

I want to deploy the contract using tezos-client originate contract command.

I am unable to init storage, tried several options.

```
--init '(Pair {} (Pair {} 0))'
```

I get the following error:

```
Ill typed data: 1: (Pair {} (Pair {} 0))
is not an expression of type map key_hash nat
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message describes the expected type: "is not an expression of type map key_hash nat"

Maps are defined with braces { } and each element starts with Elt and is delimited from others with a semi-colon. If you only have one element in your map you don't need a semi-colon.

```
--init '{ Elt "tz1account" 0 }'
```